# Set default value to member class in c#

Tags: c#, class

I need to set a default value to a member class, this value can vary and it's set at the beginning of the execution; I have this so far, minScore is my default value

```
public class Zones : GeneralIndicator
{
   public int IndicatorType { get; set; } 
   public string Code { get; set; }
   public string Score { get; set; } //TODO: calcular desde aca el score usando el indicatortype
   public double Latitude { get; set; }
   public double Longitude { get; set; }

   private int minScore = 0;

   public void setMinScore(int value)
   {
      minScore = value;
   }
}
```

I get the minScore value as a parameter when calling the application. What's the best way to set minScore for every object generated in runtime?

Comment: So you'll have multiple instances of this object, and they should all have the same `minScore` value?  Or can each one have a different `minScore`?

Comment: If defining `minScore` is required for the objects creation, consider adding a constructor.  If this comment is not related, can you elaborate on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Your question is a little bit vague. But the best way would be to set the minScore in the constructor (if I got your question right).

Comment: @AllenG yes, they should all have the same minScore value

Comment: @gunr2171, actually, I'm dumb. Redacted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two options:

- Create a `ZonesFactory` class, which takes a `defaultMinScore` in the constructor (to remember) and has a `CreateZones` method which creates an instance and sets the min score:

  ```
  public class ZonesFactory
  {
      private readonly int defaultMinScore;

      public ZonesFactory(int defaultMinScore)
      {
          this.defaultMinScore = defaultMinScore;
      }

      public Zones CreateZones()
      {
          return new Zones(defaultMinScore);
      }
  }
  ```

  Note that here I'm assuming you also create a new constructor for `Zones` which takes the `minScore` as a parameter. I suggest you get rid of the `setMinScore` method (which violates .NET naming conventions apart from anything else).
- Use a static variable to keep the default, and set it in the `Zones` constructor

Personally I'd prefer the first of these.

Comment: Jon's secondary point about `setMinScore` is important. You're mixing java convention with C#. I'd suggest having a property named `MinScore` with a public getter and private setter.

Comment: @ReacherGilt: That's assuming it needs to be accessible at all. Better to have it just as a constructor parameter, then stored in a readonly field, unless it's actually required as part of the public API.